# create sql Database from ER diagram

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: ER-Diagram]

I tried to make Kann table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Kann(
id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
MiNr integer REFERENCES Employer(MiNr),
FNr integer REFERENCES Ability(FNr)
);
```

The problem is that I want Oracle to automatically insert data in `Kann` and `Cooperation` tables, when I insert data manually in `Ability`, `Employer` and `Project` tables.

How is that possible? Should I use triggers or other PL/SQL elements or I can do it only with SQL?

Comment: I've removed the `sql server` tag, as it appears it is not involved.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7405/generate-sample-data-for-an-oracle-database

Comment: Please explain how you want Oracle to fill those fields; are they fixed values, result of a query, ... ?

Comment: as a result of insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only build Diagram from existing code [ER](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-may/o34sqldev-2193423.html)

You don`t need a triger or something else, just do [relation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61sql-512018.html) between databases. The relationship between 2 tables matches the Primary Key in one of the tables with a Foreign Key in the second table.

Or just do [Foreign Key](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) in your database. A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

Or if you alredy have a tables:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

Comment: I can do it without PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is illogical. Forget coding, SQL etc. and just think in normal language.

Table Employer lists all your employers, shown with an id number and their name. No other information. Table Abilities, similarly, shows all the recognized "abilities", identified by a number and described by a name.

From this you want Oracle (or whoever else) to know which Employer has which Ability or Abilities? HOW?

If it were possible to know which employer has which ability(ies) from anything else in the database, then you wouldn't need the Kann table in the first place (in fact, having it in the database would violate normality, which is a very desirable quality for a database in most cases).